# how to remove duplicate lines using perl script

Tags: perl, duplicates

How to remove duplicate lines?

My current code:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $input = input.txt;
my $output = output.txt;
my %seen;

open("OP",">$output") or die;
open("IP","<$input") or die;

while(my $string = <IP>) {
    my @arr1 = join("",$string);
    my @arr2 = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @arr1;
    print "@arr2\n";
    print OP "@arr2\n";
}

close("IP");
close("OP");
```

Input:

```
india
australia
america
singapore
india
america
```

Expected output :

```
india
australia
america
singapore
```

Comment: I don't know what you think that `join` statement will do, but it is in fact not doing anything.  The loop is redundant, you can just grep the whole file and print it right away. E.g. `perl -e'print grep !$seen{$_}++, <>;' input > output`

Comment: Recommended use of [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open), [Modern Perl Programming](https://www.programmer-books.com/modern-perl-4th-edition-pdf/).

Comment: @Noor Perl's `join` is used to concatenate string pieces into one string

Answer (score 4):

Use this Perl one-liner to delete **all** duplicates, whether adjacent or not:

```
perl -ne 'print unless $seen{$_}++;' input.txt > output.txt
```

To delete only **adjacent** duplicates (as in UNIX [`uniq`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) command):

```
perl -ne 'print unless $_ eq $prev; $prev = $_; ' input.txt > output.txt
```

The Perl one-liners use these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.

When the line is seen for the first time, `$seen{$_}` is evaluated first, and is false, so the line is printed. Then, `$seen{$_}` is incremented by one, which makes it true every time the line is seen again (thus the same line is not printed any more).

The first one-liner avoids reading the entire file into memory all at once, which could be important for inputs with lots of long duplicated lines. Only the first occurrence of every line is stored in memory, together with its number of occurrences.

**SEE ALSO:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: Is there a way to make it more like the `uniq` command in the sense that *only* adjacent duplicate lines are collapsed into a single line?

Comment: @Unknown Updated the answer.

Comment: Beautiful! I hope without sounding too demanding, I could ask for the moonshot: For the latter case, it'd be fantastic to print a star for each suppressed duplicate line. So, if a line appears 4 times in a row, it'll be shown once with 3 stars in front of it :)

Comment: @Unknown I suggest to ask this as a separate question. You will get more and better answers. Good luck!

Comment: I'll just code it in C. Perl is not made for mere mortals :)

Answer (score 2):

Removed unwanted line of codes from script.

Here is the updated script:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %seen;

my @lines = <DATA>;
chomp @lines;

my @contries = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @lines;
print Dumper(\@contries);

__DATA__
india
australia
america
singapore
india
america
```

Result:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'india',
          'australia',
          'america',
          'singapore'
        ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Please investigate the following code snippet, you was very close to utilize `%seen` hash.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %seen;
my @uniq;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    push @uniq, $_ unless $seen{$_};
    $seen{$_} = 1;
}

say for @uniq;

__DATA__
india
australia
america
singapore
india
america
```

Output

```
india
australia
america
singapore
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making this all far too complicated. The main section of your code can be simplified to:

```
while (<IP>) {
  print unless $seen{$_}++;
}
```

Or even:

```
print grep { ! $seen{$_}++ } <IP>;
```